# How do I differentiate between admin login and the user login from the same login template?

Tags: django, authentication, admin

How do I differentiate between admin login and the user login in Django.I want to create single login template?If the login is from the user I want to redirect into different template than the admin.

Answer (score 0):

django default user model has a field superuserstatus . it is Boolean field . if this field is checked user is admin else not. check on this condition.